# Keep process alive during shutdown

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I have two desktop apps on the same machine, let's call them Client and Server. When Windows goes into shutdown I would like to have the Client do some short housecleaning with the Server. Client knows it's closing time because in `OnFormClosing` the `FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason` is `CloseReason.WindowsShutDown`. But in the mean time the Server may be forcefully killed by the OS. Is it possible to have the Server alive for as long as possible, so that all the Clients can finish their jobs, but not halt the shutdown entirely?

- The Server does not know which Clients are alive and in need of housecleaning.
- Both Client and Server should not cause the Windows to show the message saying that the app is preventing the Windows from shutting down.

I guess I'm asking for some Windows API calls that can negotiate with Windows to kill the process last if possible, but any working solution is welcome. The Client is written in C# and the Server is written in C++.

Comment: Make *Server* a service.

Comment: @Dialecticus answer posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Server should be keeping track of the Clients that are connected to it.  So, if your apps are busy performing housecleaning, they ARE blocking shutdown, even if just momentarily.  So what is wrong with letting Windows show a message to the user saying that?

When the Server gets notified of an imminent shutdown, have it call [`ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasoncreate) if there are any Clients connected. Regardless of whether the Clients perform housecleaning or not, when the last Client disconnects then the Server can call [`ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasondestroy).

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is to make the server [a Windows service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/services#https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications).

As a stop-gap solution you can try [`SetProcessShutdownParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setprocessshutdownparameters).

> This function sets a shutdown order for a process relative to the other processes in the system.